# Accessing HTML Form elements through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can any guru show me how to get values from HTML Form element - RADIO BUTTON and CHECK BOX?

For example in case of text box we can get the value directly by getElementById(id).value;

But how to get the value for a combo box (drop down menu), radio button and checkbox ?

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: pretty much no one does it this way anymore, and instead most people use frameworks like jQuery, Mootools, etc, so that we can just do `$('#yourSelectId').val()` or `$('#yourSelectId option:selected').val()` (jquery examples).

Comment: you can do a little googling and you will find 1000s of example. put a little effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop down (`<select>`):

```
var el = document.getElementById('yourSelectId');
var value = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
```

If you're treating your select list as a multi-select (combobox) list, you have to loop through the options and check if they are selected:

```
var el = document.getElementByid('yourSelectId');
var selectedValues = [];

for (var i = 0; i < el.options.length; i++) {
    if (el.options[i].selected) {
        selectedValues.push(el.options[i].value);
    }
}

// all selected values are now in the selectedValues array.
```

Radio buttons and checkboxes should also have `value` properties, but more appropriately I think I would only test whether they are checked:

```
var isChecked = document.getElementById('yourRadioOrCheckboxId').checked;
```

Comment: `el.options[el.selectedIndex].value` can be simply `el.value`, unless you need to support really ancient browsers (NN4 and similar).

Answer (score 1):

For checkbox, the element has a `.checked` property:

```
document.getElementById('foo').checked; // true or false
```